# Direct download link for iTunes for Microsoft Windows (not from Microsoft Store)

Tags: itunes, windows

I wish to download iTunes for Windows 10. I am looking for a direct download link on Apple’s website rather than downloading it from Microsoft Store. When I visit [Apple Support - Downloads](https://support.apple.com/downloads/itunes) page, and click on the download link, It redirect me to this page:

- https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/

There it says I need to get iTunes from the Microsoft store.

I cannot use Microsoft Store at work as it is disabled by IT, but I am allowed to install and use iTunes.

Is there a direct download link for iTunes for Microsoft Windows 10 hosted somewhere on the official Apple website?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can download iTunes 12.9.1.4 for Microsoft Windows using the following direct link(s) on Apple's website:

- [iTunes for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/041-13378-20181024-3F5B4748-D7EB-11E8-AD60-F196F34A5CAA/iTunes64Setup.exe)
- [iTunes for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/041-13372-20181024-3F5AEEE2-D7EB-11E8-9F46-F296F34A5CAA/iTunesSetup.exe)

The links should work for the time being, however the same may change with subsequent updates to the software.

Comment: @Max, I'm not sure if apple.com generates a dynamic link for each individual download (I have tested these links on different computers). If they don't work for you, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be working. I've added the links to my list of useful links personal wiki.

Comment: Good to hear. Even if the links aren’t dynamically generated, I highly suspect they change with every new release of iTunes. A useful tip is to use a computer running macOS, Linux, Free BSD (any non Windows OS) to download iTunes for Windows directly from apple.com

Comment: @Max Can you please check and reply with the version of iTunes that got downloaded. Not possible to check on a Mac :(

Comment: not certain what "check and reply" is actually, but I've edited my original question with the iTunes version.

Comment: @NimeshNeema the 64 bit link is currently working and still provides version 12.9.1.4 of `iTunes64Setup.exe`.

Answer (score 8):

These are direct download links and are versionless:

https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/win64

https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/win32

Comment: This answer stands the test of time (compared to the accepted answer). I used this link to install the latest version in late April 2020 (v 12.10.6.2). Thank you for sharing the link!

Answer (score 0):

There is a legacy version for PC [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1615?locale=) (64-bit). I used to run this on Windows 7. The version is 12.1.3 but current version on high Sierra is 12.8.150.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this is typically a moving target.
[This](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-6562#versions) is an extensive list which may be useful for many but [the current version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_iTunes#iTunes_12) as of 2020-04-11 is 12.10.5.12, so the list (12.9.1.4 is the last one linked) is outdated.